# code igniter - how to update the database if a query result returns rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am constructing a query in codeigniter. If the conditions are met, I want to update the appropriate row in the database, and if they are not, I want to insert a new row. This is my code:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('extra_examples', array('question' => $data['question'],'tag' => $data['tag'] ));
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            $this->db->update('extra_examples', $data);
            return ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0);
        } else {
            $this->db->insert('extra_examples', $data);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
```

The insert works fine, and the update works if there is only one row in the entire database, but the update seems to change all rows in the database if there are more than one rows. I want it to change only the row where question = data['question'] and tag = data['tag].

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this line has the issue:

> $this->db->update('extra_examples', $data);

This line simply updates table with values `$data`. So, whenever condition is true, this will get executed and update all the rows. Try to put some condition on `$data`, so that only selected rows get affected.

What you can do is :

```
$data = array(
           // put array data
        );

$this->db->where('id', $id); // check where to put 
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

Comment: I tried doing adding this line above the update: ```$this->db-where(array('question' => $data['question'],'tag' => $data['tag'] ) );``` but it didn't work

Comment: oops, missed the ```>``` on ```db->where```. So this worked: ```$this->db->where(array('question' => $data['question'],'tag' => $data['tag'] ) );```

Comment: It happens. I hope you are not feeling sleepy :D :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('extra_examples', array('question' => $data['question'],'tag' => $data['tag'] ));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $this->db->where(array('question' => $data['question'],'tag' => $data['tag'] ))
        $this->db->update('extra_examples', $data);
        return ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0);
    } else {
        $this->db->insert('extra_examples', $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```